# Display percentage as progress

Tags: php, math

Assuming the following

1. I have n objects in a list
2. The objects are processed sequentially
3. I want to display percentage complete whenever it crosses a certain amount

For example,

I have 2204 objects once it has processed 221 objects I want it to display 10%, then once it has processed 441 objects I want it to display 20%. Essentially so that I have a guideline of where the queue is at.

Writing this in php I had the following:

```
$i = 0;
$total = 2204 // result of getTotal();

foreach (range ($i, $total) as $i ) {
    //do some irrelevant processing
    if (($i/$total*100)%10 == 0) {
        echo number_format(($i/$total*100),0)."% done.\n";
    }
}
```

However my result set is less than desirable, I get the following as output:

```
0% done.
0% done.
0% done.
0% done.
0% done.
0% done.
0% done.
0% done.
0% done.
0% done.
0% done.
0% done.
1% done.
1% done.
1% done.
1% done.
1% done.
1% done.
1% done.
1% done.
1% done.
1% done.
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: So you want only 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 etc?

Comment: You should read the floating point PHP reference :) Anyway, to "fix" this, round your value from the condition: `if(round($i/$total*100)%10 == 0)` ...

Comment: @putvande Essentially yes, but for multiples of 10 up to 100.

Comment: @onetrickpony That works but I end up with approximately 10 0% done, 10 10% done, 10 20$ done. etc. I only want it to be displayed once.

Comment: Then store the last value, and in the next iteration you compare it with the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
$total = 2204;

foreach (range ($i, $total) as $i ) {
    if ($i % floor($total/100) == 0) {
        echo number_format(($i/$total*100),0)."% done.\n";
    }
}
```

If you want it only each 10% (10,20,30...100) and not to include the 0 you could do :

```
$i = 0;
$total = 2204;

foreach (range ($i, $total) as $i ) {
    if ($i % floor($total/10) == 0 && $i > 0) {
        echo number_format(($i/$total*100),0)."% done.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This results in displaying 301 results when there should only be 10 (maybe 11 if you include 0%).

Comment: 301 results? To me it shows 0% ... 100%. Are you using this exact code?

Answer (score 1):

There is another problem I see with the logic you have here:

Since you are incrementing through this list by +1 you will not get exact 10%, 20%.
For example when I do following:

```
foreach (range ($i, $total) as $i ) {
    echo $i/$total."\n";
}
```

you will see

```
0.19555353901996
0.19600725952813
0.1964609800363
0.19691470054446
0.19736842105263
0.1978221415608
0.19827586206897
0.19872958257713
0.1991833030853
0.19963702359347
0.20009074410163
0.2005444646098
0.20099818511797
0.20145190562613
```

You will probably want to round these off after multiplying by 100 and maintain a separate array where you will check to see if you have already displayed these values.

Sample program:

```
foreach (range ($i, $total) as $i ) {
    $val = round($i/$total*100)%10;
    $num = number_format(($i/$total*100),0);
if ($val == 0) {
    if(!in_array($num, $check)){
            $check[] =  $num;
            echo $num."% done.\n";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

my 2p answer would be to use a check variable

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$total = 2204; // result of getTotal()
$boundary=10;

foreach (range ($i, $total) as $i ) {
    //do some irrelevant processing
    $ii=intval(($i/$total)*100);
    if($ii>=$boundary){
        echo $boundary . "% done.\n";
        $boundary+=10;
    }
}

?>
```